# Number of Spring Contexts created by ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

It is easily to know how many contexts have been created if we create `ApplicationContext` instances programmatically. However, how many context are created if we use `ContextLoaderListener`? For example Spring's [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#context-create) as below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

It has 2 context xml files. Does it means 2 contexts are created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextLoaderListener` creates only one application context containing all beans from files selected in `contextConfigLocation`. Bean definitions are merged together and form a single context.

However if you use Spring MVC, the framework will create one extra child context per each `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 1):

Only one context is created - only one root application context exists.

> Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext.

If you look at the code of `ContextLoader` - it creates a `WebApplicationContext` using the `contextConfigLocation` param (which is later parsed by the context)